# Custom post-steps after FetchContent

Tags: cmake, fetchcontent

I am working on a mocking library for C that is meant to be easy to use and portable so I decided to use CMake as the backbone. A user would include this (non-binary) library with

```
include(FetchContent)

# Fetch UMock
FetchContent_Declare(
    umock
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/debuti/umock.git
    GIT_SHALLOW    1
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(umock)
include(${umock_SOURCE_DIR}/umock/cmake/umock.cmake)
```

But I don't really like the `include()` and it would ideally be removed. I don't know how to do that, maybe FetchContent_MakeAvailable can do that for me or maybe there is another workaround. Is there a way to perform custom post-steps when fetching content?

Comment: `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` is effectively `add_subdirectory` which descends into a subproject. It won't do anything more about the subproject. If you want the subproject to be usable without additional `include`, then add this functionality into the subproject itself.

Comment: Precisely, that did it!